# Export Excel from SQL Server database using Asp.net & Vb.net supports Arabic language

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, excel

Please help

How to export Excel from a SQL Server table using Asp.net & Vb.net supporting Arabic language?

I have used this code:

```
    Dim cmdText As String = "SELECT * FROM ReportView"
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(cmdText, Conn)
    Conn.Open()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)
    Conn.Close()
    Dim GridView1 As New GridView()
    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.xls")
    Dim sw As New StringWriter()
    Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw)
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
```

But the problem occurs after export Excel file where the words appear as incomprehensible

```
Ù…Ø­Ù…Ø¯ Ø¨Ù† Ø±Ø§Ø´Ø¯ Ø¢Ù„ Ù…ÙƒØªÙˆÙ… Ø§Ù„Ø«Ø§Ù†ÙˆÙŠØ© Ù„Ù„Ø¨Ù†ÙŠÙ† (Ø§Ù„Ù…Ø²Ø±Ø¹Ø© Ø§Ù„Ø´Ø±Ù‚ÙŠØ©)
```

Comment: What are the **datatypes** of your columns in SQL Server??

Comment: nvarchar datatypes columns  Please help......

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong MIME content type (`"application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8"`).

You cannot generate an actual Excel (`*.xls` or `*.xlsx`) file from ASP.NET as they are both complicated file formats (XLS is binary, XLSX is a zip-compressed series of XML documents).

What your code currently does it render a HTML `<table>` (by abusing the `GridView` control) and assuming Excel will see it's a HTML table and read it accordingly.

Instead, please either generate a CSV file or output an actual HTML file with the necessary `xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\\ xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"` attributes and elements added.

Because you're abusing Excel's file reader it cannot properly interpret your text content, note the `charset` attribute of your `Content-Type` header is ignored by Excel. I believe (though cannot prove) that Excel reads files as Latin1 (or some other 1-byte Western-language encoding) and does not default to UTF-8, even in HTML files unless there's a `<meta />` element that specifies the encoding used, but you're only rendering a HTML fragment, a `<table>` element, without any metadata, which is another reason why it isn't reading it correctly.